# Why is a new user allowed to enter a duplicate title, but I (a moderator) am not?

Tags: bug

New, duplicate question is:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/14147734/102937

Original is:

[The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297216)

I chose a different duplicate to close.  When I tried adding the second duplicate to the question, the SE software blocked my edit, stating that the title (which the OP typed in) already exists.

Note that the "Duplicate Title" error appears, even though the new user typed a period at the end of the title.  Such periods are supposed to be removed automatically by the system.  *It is probably the removal of the period from my edit that caused the duplication,* so the real bug is this didn't happen for the OP.

Comment: Sounds like you have a prblam

Comment: There appears to be a slight difference (a period at the end).

Comment: @JoshMein: I still get the "Duplicate Title" error, even though I leave the period in.  Periods are supposed to be removed from the end of the title anyway, which the new user is also apparently exempt from; that's a bug too.

Comment: Is it because the original question was asked before there were title restrictions?

Comment: Possibly.  It seems unlikely that the automatic period removal would be tied to duplicate title detection, though.  I've edited my question to make it clearer which one is which.

Comment: you moderators just have too little power

Comment: @gnat Or they just *want* too much power ;)

Comment: @Robert - we _do_ use ElasticSearch as well for duplicate title detection. Not sure what the implications are, but am looking into this.